# Content disappear from my XML using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I have a simple XML structure from which I want to extract the data then process it. I'm using Python and `xml.etree.ElementTree`, and it works well, except for a particular case. When I parse a particular XML, there is one node that returns `None` as values for the content of the elements.

Here is the code and the output:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

sample = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">\
  <file original="global" datatype="plaintext" source-language="en" target-language="fr-CA">\
    <body>\
      <trans-unit id="translations.amountMoreString" resname="e438d8a3237fefa5ace76eae98c157bd">\
        <source xml:lang="en"><ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> more</source>\
        <target xml:lang="fr-CA" state="signed-off"><ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> de plus</target>\
      </trans-unit>\
      <trans-unit id="translations.amountString" resname="7cdc0d444b4ee4ccc0a11819a3f96af2">\
        <source xml:lang="en">Amount</source>\
        <target xml:lang="fr-CA" state="signed-off">Quantité</target>\
      </trans-unit>\
    </body>\
  </file>\
</xliff>'

xliff_root = ET.fromstring(sample)

for file_element in xliff_root:
    for body_element in file_element:
        for trans_unit_element in body_element:
            print('\ntrans-unit element', trans_unit_element)

            for text_element in trans_unit_element:
                print('\tText element:', text_element)
                if text_element.tag == '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}source':
                    print('\t\tSource:', text_element.text)
                    translation_unit['source'] = text_element.text
                elif text_element.tag == '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}target':
                    print('\t\tTarget:', text_element.text)
                    translation_unit['target'] = text_element.text
```

The output:

```
trans-unit element <Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}trans-unit' at 0x00000163DBAA71D0>
    Text element: <Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}source' at 0x00000163DBAA72C0>
        Source: None
    Text element: <Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}target' at 0x00000163DBAA7450>
        Target: None

trans-unit element <Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}trans-unit' at 0x00000163DBAA7590>
    Text element: <Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}source' at 0x00000163DBAA75E0>
        Source: Amount
    Text element: <Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}target' at 0x00000163DBAA7630>
        Target: Quantité
```

I'm getting `None` as values for the `<source>` and `<target>` elements for the first `<trans-unit>`, but the second one returned the correct values. I understand that there are other elements inside the `<source>` and `<target>` elements, but there is also textual content.

I would like to thank in advance anyone who could help me understand and correct this issue...

Kind regards,

JF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @larsks answers + some digging in the documentation, I managed to get exactly what I need. I found the `ET.tostring` method that returns the whole node as text string, then I use a couple of REs to remove the unwanted stuff from those strings.

Full code here:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

sample = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">\
  <file original="global" datatype="plaintext" source-language="en" target-language="fr-CA">\
    <body>\
      <trans-unit id="translations.amountMoreString" resname="e438d8a3237fefa5ace76eae98c157bd">\
        <source xml:lang="en"><ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> more</source>\
        <target xml:lang="fr-CA" state="signed-off"><ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> de plus</target>\
      </trans-unit>\
      <trans-unit id="translations.amountString" resname="7cdc0d444b4ee4ccc0a11819a3f96af2">\
        <source xml:lang="en">Amount</source>\
        <target xml:lang="fr-CA" state="signed-off">Quantité</target>\
      </trans-unit>\
    </body>\
  </file>\
</xliff>
'''

xliff_root = ET.fromstring(sample)
translation_unit = {}

for trans_unit in xliff_root.findall('.//{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}trans-unit'):
    source = trans_unit.find('{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}source')
    source_text = ET.tostring(source, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8')
    source_text = re.sub(r'^<?(.*?)?>\n', r'', source_text)
    source_text = re.sub(r'<(\/?)ns\d+:', r'<\1', source_text)
    source_text = re.sub(r'<(\/?)source(.*?)>', r'', source_text)
    print(source_text)

    target = trans_unit.find('{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}target')
    target_text = ET.tostring(target, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8')
    target_text = re.sub(r'^<?(.*?)?>\n', r'', target_text)
    target_text = re.sub(r'<(\/?)ns\d+:', r'<\1', target_text)
    target_text = re.sub(r'<(\/?)target(.*?)>', r'', target_text)
    print(target_text)
```

Results:

```
<ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> more        
<ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> de plus      
Amount        
Quantité
```

Big thank you to @larsks also for showing me a more efficient way to parse XML documents using XPATH and the `.findall` & `.find` methods! :-)

JF

Answer (score 0):

IN the first `<trans-unit>` element, `<source>` does not contain only text; it contains a `<ph>` element. The structure is:

```
xliff
  body
    trans-unit
      source
        ph
          "text is here"
        "text is also here"
```

Compare the second `trans-unit` element, where the structure is:

```
xliff
  body
    trans-unit
      source
        "text is here"
```

You can use the `itertext` method to extract all the text children.  For example, this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

sample='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">
  <file original="global" datatype="plaintext" source-language="en" target-language="fr-CA">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="translations.amountMoreString" resname="e438d8a3237fefa5ace76eae98c157bd">
        <source xml:lang="en"><ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> more</source>
        <target xml:lang="fr-CA" state="signed-off"><ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> de plus</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="translations.amountString" resname="7cdc0d444b4ee4ccc0a11819a3f96af2">
        <source xml:lang="en">Amount</source>
        <target xml:lang="fr-CA" state="signed-off">Quantité</target>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
'''

xliff_root = ET.fromstring(sample)
translation_unit = {}

for trans_unit in xliff_root.findall('.//{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}trans-unit'):
    source = trans_unit.find('{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}source')
    source_text = [text.strip() for text in source.itertext()][-1]
    target = trans_unit.find('{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}target')
    target_text = [text.strip() for text in target.itertext()][-1]

    print('source:', source_text)
    print('target:', target_text)
```

Produces:

```
source: more
target: de plus
source: Amount
target: Quantité
```

Comment: Hello @larsks, this works and it is great, thanks!

I do have 2 additional questions however...

1) What if I also need to retried the elements (and their content) from the `<source>` and `<target>` elements? In other words, I need the full "`<ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> more`" and "`<ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> de plus`"
2) What is the meaning/purpose of the `[-1]` on the lines where the text is striped?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: A list index of `[-1]` retrieves the last item from the list. If you want all the text values, just use the whole list instead.

Comment: Hello again @larsks,
This works, I'm getting all the textual content, including the text inside the `<ph>` elements, however I also need the `<ph>` elements as plain text (or any embedded element for that matter).  So in short, my variables `source_text` and `target_text` should contain respectively `<ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> more` and `<ph id="1" ctype="x-phrase-placeholder">{{ count }}</ph> de plus` as plain text. Is this feasible?